# Unable to save domain objects until CRUD scaffold is used

Tags: grails, controller, persistence

I'm having the strangest problem with a controller in a Grails project. I am trying to do a simple update of a domain object. Here is a simplified version of the controller

```
def updateRecord = {
    def foundHVT = Process.get(params.hvt)

    foundHVT.summaryBy = params.summaryBy
    foundHVT.catalogBy = params.catalogBy
    foundHVT.editBy = params.editBy
    foundHVT.produceBy = params.produceBy
    foundHVT.correctedBy = params.correctedBy
    // a bunch more of these

    foundHVT.save(flush: true);

    redirect (action:resource, id: params.hvt)
}
```

If I run the a new instance of the application of and use this controller to update an object, it doesn't work, the object doesn't save. It will look fine within the controller. I can, for example, re-query the object and the changes are there, post  save.

Now here's where it gets weird. If i use the preset scaffold edit controller and update/save an domain object -- and then switch back to this "updateRecord" controller it works FINE until i shut down the server it is working on?!?

I realize I am missing something very basic, but I can't find what it is. Any guidance would be most graciously appreciated.

DM

Comment: something sounds off.  have you tried grails clean?

Comment: also, are you getting any exceptions?   did you enable sql logging?

Comment: yes, sorry, I did have that, I was just sketching out the basics of the controller, and it was reporting no errors at all. It's been running fine since Cleaning the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As HVGOTCODES noted Grails Clean seems to have fixed whatever weirdness was going on with this controller.

Answer (score 0):

try putting a "def scaffold=true" in your controller if it does not already have the normal entry points.

Answer (score 0):

Probably scaffolding `save` fills some field that you don't.

Possible problems:

1. Do check `save()` result and render `foundHVT.errors` the way Grails does. Add `failOnError: true` parameter to `save()` or just check `foundHVT.hasErrors()`. Look at `foundHVT.errors.allErrors` for validation problems.
2. Why not `foundHVT.properties = params`?
3. What is there is no `foundHVT`?